# User controlled css styles with PHP

Tags: php, css, stylesheet

How do I allow the users to switch between alternate CSS styles using PHP? I want them to be able to choose from a list which one they want to use, and let the site automatically switch to that CSS style. Have no idea how to do this, and the only thing I found about this was [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/user-controlled-css-file), but I didn't manage to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this ?

```
<form method="post" action="style.php">
   <select name="style">
       <option value="style1.css">Style 1</option>
       <option value="style2.css">Style 2</option>
   </select>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['style'])
{
   setcookie("style",$_POST['style']);
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['style'])
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$_COOKIE[\'style\']">';
```

Comment: I see. How do I add a button/list to it?

Comment: You can create a list in a form and save the value into a cookie.